# Compiler error when using variable as a function

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to compile some Typescript and I'm getting a compiler error:

```
TypeError: myVariable is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/anon/Desktop/Typescript/main.js:37:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:738:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:749:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:630:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:570:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:801:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:21:11
```

I'm sure this is because myVariable is indeed not a function, but is of type 'any'. This data type, however, should be accessible as a function if I'm not mistaken.

Thank you

```
let myVariable: any = 10;

console.log(myVariable.name);
console.log();
myVariable();
```

Comment: You mean the JavaScript `Number` data type should be accessible as a function?

Comment: I'm following this tutorial:

Comment: Well, `any` is really just telling the TypeScript compiler that the variable could be of any type, and what you're actually assigning to the variable is a number. So, effectively, you're trying to run something like `10()`, which of course, fails. What exactly are you trying to do by "calling" a number?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm following This tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WBPrJSw7yQA at around 24:00 minute mark the instructor demonstrates printing the 'myVariable' variable to the console. He says that because the variable is of type 'any' that the 'myVariable' variable should be accessible by the following methods;      console.log(myVariable.name);
myVariable();
myVariable.toUpperCase();

Comment: Ah I see. When the narrator says TypeScript is not throwing any errors (at 23:30), he is not talking about compilation errors (from running the `tsc` program). He is referring to the TypeScript linter, which checks your code for problems in your text editor _before_ you compile. You'll notice that there are no red "squiggles" underneath the `myVariable()` line. However, when he switches the type to `unknown`, the squiggles appear. Those squiggles are the errors he's talking about-- the code is never meant to be run.

Comment: Oh ok, that makes more sense now. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help. I'd be very grateful if you could upvote my answer and mark it as correct, too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the narrator says TypeScript is not throwing any errors (at 23:30), he is not talking about compilation errors (from running the tsc program). He is referring to the TypeScript linter, which checks your code for problems in your text editor before you compile. You'll notice that there are no red "squiggles" underneath the myVariable() line. However, when he switches the type to unknown, the squiggles appear. Those squiggles are the errors he's talking about-- the code is never meant to be run.